# Colorize a point cloud in a web page based on a scalar field?

Tags: las, point-cloud, pdal, cloudcompare

#### The issue:

I have a a [PLY](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PLY_(file_format)) point cloud file computed from a photogrammetric acquisition that has been processed in [CloudCompare](https://www.danielgm.net/cc/).

The header looks like this:

```
ply
format binary_little_endian 1.0
comment Created by CloudCompare v2.10-alpha
comment Created 24.08.18 17:12
obj_info Generated by CloudCompare!
element vertex 2162869
property float x
property float y
property float z
property uchar red
property uchar green
property uchar blue
property float nx
property float ny
property float nz
property float scalar_C2C_absolute_distances[2D1/2_Triangulation][k=6]_(X)
property float scalar_C2C_absolute_distances[2D1/2_Triangulation][k=6]_(Y)
property float scalar_C2C_absolute_distances[2D1/2_Triangulation][k=6]
property float scalar_Temp._approx._distances
property float scalar_Approx._distances
property float scalar_C2C_absolute_distances[2D1/2_Triangulation][k=6]_(Z)
end_header
```

One can see some extra **[scalar fields](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scalar_field)** in addition to the standard [XYZ](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cartesian_coordinate_system), [RGB](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RGB_color_model) and [normals](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normal_(geometry)) values. These extra fields are useful to colorize the cloud in CloudCompare based on some analysis, here for example the distance from a reference cloud.

I would like to display such cloud on a web page. All tools I met, for example [Potree](https://pdfs.semanticscholar.org/0d9d/db7335331d28a4a23e086e960396fd4e1b65.pdf) tiles, or [Cesium 3D Tiles](https://github.com/AnalyticalGraphicsInc/3d-tiles) are using 3D tiles in LAS or LAZ format.

But the LAS [ASPRS specification](https://www.asprs.org/wp-content/uploads/2010/12/LAS_1_4_r13.pdf) only allows for predefined and strictly constrained fields, which is a good thing. Naturally, most of these fields do not exist when the point cloud is *not* acquired by a [LIDAR](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lidar).
And I just didn't find some extra empty fields for any user-defined values.

#### The question:

Do you know a way to keep the scalar field values from the PLY file up to the display of 3D tiles in a web browser so that they can be used to colorize the cloud in the web page?

#### Edit:

As [sugested](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/294307/colorize-a-point-cloud-in-a-web-page-based-on-a-scalar-field?noredirect=1#comment474392_294307): I cannot convert the PLY file with [PotreeConverter](https://github.com/potree/PotreeConverter) directly, the output is buggy, I end up with inf coordinates so I have to convert the PLY file to a LAS file before using PotreeConverter. This is where I lose the scalar field information because the LAS file format is standardized and doesn't accept other fields.

Comment: Keep monitoring iTowns. They have a plan to add support for PLY data format. See https://github.com/iTowns/itowns/wiki/Supported-Features.

Comment: What happens when you convert the PLY file to Potree file format? See https://github.com/potree/potree/issues/147.